# Do i need to pin data when working with C# and C++/CX

Tags: c#, c++-cx

When sending data up and down the layers between C# and C++/CX, do i need to pin the data, before I was using the `GCHandleType.Pinned`, do I still need it, or not as now I have migrated to `C++/CX` ? if so how should I do it ? the same way as before ?

Thanks !!

Comment: C++/CX is still native code, it doesn't use .NET at all.  If pinning was necessary before then it is still necessary now.

Comment: However I don't think as an app developer that necessarily means that you need to explicitly pin - as that appears to be taken care of by the Windows Runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should need to pin data.  Pinning meant that the garbage collector would not compact your object, causing native pointer references to go awry.  With WinRT, your class is a COM object, which is reference-counted, not garbage-collected.  So the object lives on the native heap and will not be compacted/relocated.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am sending the data down without pinning, and hoping that the data does not go awry, will do some tests and will let you know how in which cases I had to pin the data, basic tests showed that it did not blow up :P

Comment: It does get fun when you consider a .NET object which implements an interface class defined in C++/CX - does that get ref-counted or garbage collected (or both)?

Comment: good point Paul, not sure about it tho, my guess is that who ever creates the object calls its garbage collector but again that is my assumption, can spare a few minutes to search for it but i doubt that i will find anything, resources on C++/CX is very low.. :/

Comment: Any public class implementing a *WinRT* interface (regardless of which language the interface or class is defined in) is, at its heart, reference counted, because it is activated by the Windows Runtime.

In .NET, they create RCW (runtime-callable wrappers). Essentially, it is an object that lives on the GC which contains a single refcount to a class activated by the Windows Runtime.  That RCW is tracked via GC, and when no more references to it exist, it is cleaned up and its single refcount to the WinRT object decrements, cleaning up that underlying object.

Comment: @AndyRich so there are 2 objects (one in managed heap and one in native heap) ?

Comment: Yes.  There is an object in the native heap (which is the true instance of the object), and a wrapper object in the managed heap that managed languages call through.  That wrapper object is tracked by the GC heap and when it is cleaned up by GC it cleans up the underlying native object.